# I am trying to convert a java unittest case mockito to Kotlin MockK in android

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mockk

This is the verify block and was working on java

```
verify(mockTokenError) {}
```

And later tried to convert to kotlin

```
verify{mockTokenError()}
```

also tried

```
verify{mockTokenError}
```

none of them works please let me know solution.

Answer (score 1):

So the `verify` block checks all method calls (which were made with the mocked object) that are inside its block.
For example,

```
val car = mockk<Car>()

verify { car.stop() }
```

More info - https://mockk.io/#verification-atleast-atmost-or-exactly-times